# shift() and pop() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

So i was making a random quote generator machine project for learning purposes and encountered a error.
I tried looking for it in other answers but couldn't understand/solve it.
here is the JS code:

```
    $('#new').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax( {
      url: 'https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=mycallback',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var post = data.shift(); // The data is an array of posts. Grabbing the first one.
        $('.author').text(post.title);
        console.log(post.title);
        $('.quote').html(post.content);
        console.log(post.content);
      },
      cache: false
    });
  });
```

For the first console.log it shows data in form of array, So I tried pop and shift functions to extract the data. here is the format of data:

```
/**/mycallback([{"ID":1640,"title":"Scott Belsky","content":"<p>To envision what will be, you must remove yourself from the constant concern for what already is.<\/p>\n","link":"https:\/\/quotesondesign.com\/scott-belsky\/","custom_meta":{"Source":"<a href=\"http:\/\/the99percent.com\/book\">book<\/a>"}}])
```

It gave undefined for the next 2 console.log() .
Here is the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: data.shift is not a function

and it gave errors on both functions. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The response is a JSONP string, not JSON. Set `dataType: 'jsonp'` on the request

Comment: Side note: `shift` is a highly inefficient way to grab the first entry from an array. `var post = data[0];` would be the usual way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

- Don't define the callback function. Leave that to `$.ajax` by replacing the explicit function name to `?`
- Set the data type to `jsonp`

```js
$.ajax( {
    url: 'https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=?',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var post = data.shift();
      console.log(post);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Could you please explain why it worked and previous code didn't ?

Comment: In your code, the request goes through as `json`. In this case,  the expected response is `JSON` but rather the server returns `jsonp` because you already passed `_jsonp` so jQuery ignores running callback. However, when setting `dataType` to `jsonp` jQuery will execute a defined function in the global context (`window`) and you get your data to work with.